# layout not inflate in fragment after transaction from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate

This is a onclick item listener in activity class from where an object named movieTagsItem is passed

```
public void onItemClick(MovieTagsItem movieTagsItem) {
        Log.d(TAG,"It is clicked");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.news_details, MovieProfile2.newInstanceFromMovieTags(movieTagsItem));
        ft.commit();

    }
```

this is my fragment class where the object is called and executed. the problem is i am not able to inflate layout as define in onCreatView

```
public class MovieProfile2 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = MovieProfile2.class.getSimpleName();

    MovieProfile movieInfo;

    public static MovieProfile2 newInstanceFromMovieTags(MovieTagsItem movieTagsItem) {



        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("movieTag", movieTagsItem);
        MovieProfile2 fragment = new MovieProfile2();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movie_profile2, container,false);
        Log.d(TAG, "layout is working: "+ inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_movie_profile2, container,false));



        MovieTagsItem movieTagsItem = (MovieTagsItem)getArguments().getSerializable("movieTag");
        Log.d(TAG, "Movie Id: "+ movieTagsItem.getMovieId());

          int id = movieTagsItem.getMovieId();

return view;
}
```

}

This is my fragment layout which is supposed to inflate after performing onclick action from activity class where require data are coming but the layout is not showing up

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_movie_tag_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_movie_tag_Movie_Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/movie_name"
                android:textSize="25sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv__movie_tag_Name_Nepali"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/name_nepali"
                android:textSize="20sp">

            </TextView>



            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_movie_tag_released_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@string/released_date"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_movie_tag_run_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/run_time"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_released_date"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

            </FrameLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    >

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_tag_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_action_search" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_movie_tag_synopsis"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movie_image"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:text="@string/synopsis"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </FrameLayout>





        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: you want to open MovieProfile2 ?

Comment: yes ... i want to open MovieProfile2 fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace your ***news_details*** fragment, but In your fragment XML there is nothing that matches the id for ***layout_movie_profile2***.

Comment: i am a newbie and i don't have knowledge about fragments.. what i am trying to do is to replace news_details which is actually a activity layout with a fragment named MovieProfile2 with a layout named layout_movie_profile2

Answer (score 0):

Try this pass id into news_details in define xml file in contact id like that below code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


</FrameLayout>
```

then after define that id into replace fragment..

```
 ft.replace(R.id.content_main, MovieProfile2.newInstanceFromMovieTags(movieTagsItem)).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```